# UAudioComponent Plays a sound over and over

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

here is the code

the code is supposed to play a walking sound when moving forward and stop when not moving but instead it plays the sound everyframe that makes a horrible noise what is wrong here?

in cppp

```
void AMain::MoveRight(float Value)
{
    if (!bIsDead && Value != 0.0f)
    {
        // add movement in that direction
        AddMovementInput(GetActorRightVector(), Value);
        if (!IsValid(WalkingSound))
        {
            WalkingSound = UGameplayStatics::SpawnSound2D(this, SoundBase);
            UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Play"));
        }
        bIsMovingRight = true;

    }
    else if (Value == 0.0f && IsValid(WalkingSound))
    {
        bIsMovingRight = false;
        WalkingSound->Stop();
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Stop"));
    }
    
}
```

in .h

```
UPROPERTY(EditDefaultsOnly)
        class USoundBase* SoundBase;

    class UAudioComponent* WalkingSound;
```

Comment: `WalkingSound` should be a `UPROPERTY`.

Comment: when i mark it as a UPROPERTY nothing shows up in the editor

Comment: What do you mean by shows up? This is audio

Comment: yep that was the problem but i still don't know whats the point of making it a UPROPERTY

Comment: `UPROPERTY` makes a reference to it. If there are no references to it then it will be marked for garbage collection, and `IsValid` will return false.

Comment: yep, thanks for the help.